# i18n with Next.js 13 - language cookie reverts to default language on refresh

Tags: reactjs, typescript, cookies, internationalization, next.js13

I'm building a Next.js 13 project and use i18n for translation handling. I have the translations stored in the respective JSON files and my i18n.tsx is set up like this:

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

i18n.use(Backend)
    .use(LanguageDetector)
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .init({
        fallbackLng: ['en'],
        detection: {
            order: [
                'htmlTag',
                'querystring',
                'cookie',
                'localStorage',
                'sessionStorage',
                'navigator',
                'path',
                'subdomain',
            ],
            // cache user language on
            caches: ['cookie'],
        },
        react: {
            useSuspense: true,
        },
        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false,
        },
    });

export default i18n;
```

When I run the app, the language choice is stored in the cookies under a value of i18next, which upon start up is set as *en*. I use English and Czech that I switch between with buttons mapped into this component:

```
import {
    Box,
    List,
    ListItem,
    ListItemButton,
    ListItemText,
} from '@mui/material';
import { FC } from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

interface Language {
    nameEng: string;
    name: string;
    value: string;
}

const languageList = [
    {
        nameEng: 'UK',
        name: 'English',
        value: 'en',
    },
    {
        nameEng: 'Czech',
        name: 'Čeština',
        value: 'cs',
    },
];

export const LanguageList: FC = () => {
    const { i18n } = useTranslation();

    return (
        <Box sx={{ width: '100%', minWidth: 200, bgcolor: 'background.paper' }}>
            <nav>
                <List>
                    {languageList.map((lang: Language) => (
                        <ListItem key={lang.name} disablePadding>
                            <ListItemButton
                                selected={lang.value === i18n.language}
                                onClick={() => i18n.changeLanguage(lang.value)}
                                style={{ textAlign: 'right' }}
                            >
                                <ListItemText>
                                    <span
                                        style={{
                                            color: '#697586',
                                            fontSize: '0.75rem',
                                        }}
                                    >{`(${lang.nameEng})`}</span>{' '}
                                    {`${lang.name}`}
                                </ListItemText>
                            </ListItemButton>
                        </ListItem>
                    ))}
                </List>
            </nav>
        </Box>
    );
};
```

Switching languages works fine but when I use Czech language and refresh the page, the language then switches back to English, even though it was correctly set as *cs* in the cookie. Even the cookie itself reverts back to *en* instead of *cs*.
Shouldn't the cookie persist and hold the value which was set into it even after refresh?

Btw, I do not have the app folder, the _app.tsx is in the src/pages folder.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Were you able to find a solution?